# The New line (\n) wasn't selected in Django admin changelist page

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have added a small function in list_display to display many to many fields and I am trying to display the m2m objects seperated by newline.
but the newline seperator wasn't working

My django admin:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_filter = ["category",]
     list_display = ('category','article_type', 'get_domains')
     filter_horizontal = ("domain",)

     def get_domains(self, obj):
        x ="\n".join([str(s.name) for s in obj.domain.all()])
        print x  # printing fine
        return x

     get_domains.short_description = 'Domains'
```

The print statement does well:

```
   0 errors found
   Django version 1.4.5, using settings 'settings'
   Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
   Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
   mykitchenremodelinglosangeles.com:8000
   kitchenremodelerchicagoil.com:8000
   localhost:8000
```

I have attached the admin screen output:

[image]

could you suggest this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

New lines are ignored by browsers in HTML. If you want to show them in different lines I think you should `join`  them with `<br>` instead of `\n` and use `allow_tags`.

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ["category",]
    list_display = ('category','article_type', 'get_domains')
    filter_horizontal = ("domain",)

    def get_domains(self, obj):
        x ="<br>".join([str(s.name) for s in obj.domain.all()])
        print x  # printing fine
        return x

    get_domains.allow_tags = True
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: There maybe are other ways but why bother? This is simple and the way `docs` recommend so it's good to do it that way :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_filter = ["category",]
     list_display = ('category','article_type', 'get_domains')
     filter_horizontal = ("domain",)

     def get_domains(self, obj):
        x ="<br>".join([str(s.name) for s in obj.domain.all()])
        return x

     get_domains.short_description = 'Domains'
     get_domains.allow_tags=True
```

It has done the job simply !!! django admin is cool :-)

Is there any other way apart from this?